# How to echo in PHP, HTML tags

Tags: php, html, tags, echo

I went through this before posting:

*[How can I echo HTML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/easiest-way-to-echo-html-in-php)*

And I still couldn't make it work.

I'm trying to echo this:

```
<div>
    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

But I still can't find a way to make the tags "" and '' disappear. What do I have to do?

Comment: Thanks so much to all of you! I will see which answer fits best and is best voted (to accept one). But again thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<?php

echo '<div>
 <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
 <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<div>';

?>
```

Just put it in single quotes.

Comment: just remember to escape any ' you might have in your html with backslash like this \'

Comment: This is not working for me.I write following code                  echo '<a href="google.com"><img src="newone.jpg" /></a>';                                                                    it produce the output as "<\/a>" with double quotation.

Answer (score 12):

Try the *heredoc*-based solution:

```
echo <<<HTML
<div>
    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
<div>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 8):

Using the first mechanism given there will do it.

```
<?php
  ...
?>
<div>
 <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
 <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<div>
<?php
  ...
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `"` so that PHP doesn't recognise them as part of your PHP code. You do this by using the `\` escape character.

So, your code would look like this:

```
echo
    "<div>
        <h3><a href=\"#\">First</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
    <div>"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to output large quantities of HTML you should consider using [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax. This will allow you to write your strings without the need for escaping.

```
echo <<<EOD
You can put "s and 's here if you like.
EOD;
```

Also note that because PHP is an *embedded language* you can add it between you HTML content and you don't need to echo any tags.

```
<div>
    <p>No PHP here!</p>
    <?php
    $name = "Marcel";
    echo "<p>Hello $name!</p>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Also if you just want to output a variable you should use the short-hand output tags `<?=$var?>`. This is equivalent to `<?php echo $var; ?>`.

Answer (score 4):

Separating HTML from PHP is the best method. It's less confusing and easy to debug.

```
<?php
  while($var)
  {
?>

     <div>
         <h3><a href="User<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></h3>
         <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
     </div>

<?php
  $i++;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a variety of options. One would be to use PHP as the template engine it is:

```
<?php 
  // Draw the page
?>
<div>
  <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
<?php
  // Done drawing.
?>
```

Another would be to use single quotes, which let you leave double quotes unquoted and also support newlines in literals:

```
<?php
  echo '<div>
  <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>';
?>
```

Another would be to use a HEREDOC, which leaves double quotes untouched, supports newlines, and also expands any variables inside:

```
<?php
  echo <<<EOS
<div>
  <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
EOS;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace '<' with `&lt;` and '>' with `&gt;`. For example:

```
echo "&lt;div&gt;";
```

The output will be visible `<div>`.

For longer strings, make a function, for example

```
function example($input) {
    $output = str_replace('>', '&gt;', str_replace('<', '&lt;', $html));
    return $output;
}

echo example($your_html);
```

Don't forget to put backslashes `href=\"#\"` or do it with single quotes `href='#'` or change it in a function too with str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to use echo, sir. Just use the tag <plaintext>:

```
<plaintext>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an ending tag?

Comment: The <plaintext> tag is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Use the <pre> tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work fine with double quotes. To *echo* any html_tag with double quotes we just need to remember one thing, *Do not use any other double quotes(") in the middle*.

```
<?php
    echo "
    <div>
        <h3><a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931351/how-to-echo-in-php-html-tags'>First</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
    <div>";
?>
```

Notice here the link inside the PHP *echo* is enclosed within the single quotes. This is the precaution you should take while using the double quotes for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added code, the way you want line by line.

The `.=` helps you to echo multiple lines of code.

```
$html = '<div>';
$html .= '<h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>';
$html .= '<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<div>';
echo $html;
```