# How do I echo the original HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, echo, server-side

I have some HTML. In my HTML, there is a form that uses a PHP script. When I submit this form, it sends me to a blank page. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931351/how-to-echo-in-php-html-tags), as suggested in a similar question, but it doesn't work because I have HTML events that call functions with arguments, so both " and ' are already used... I am new to PHP, so, is a there a solution to this that I do not know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the backslash character `\` to escape your quotes like so `\"`. The backslash causes PHP to treat the quote as a regular character. :]

Example:

`<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>`
outputs `Hello World`

`<?php echo "\"Hello World\""; ?>` outputs `"Hello World"`

Answer (score 1):

Escape your quotes.

```
echo "<h3><a href=\"somewhere.html\">First</a></h3>"
```

`\"` is an escaped quote. When a quote is escaped, the environment treats it as an ordinary character, not as a quote. `\'` Single quotes can also be escaped if need be.

(Not the best example since I'm not also using singles, but you get the point.)

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try. I can only imagine how long it could take to escape all of the quotes in this piece of code though, there are quite a few!

Comment: If your HTML output is stored within a PHP variable, you can simply use the addslashes() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function to escape your HTML.

Comment: You could also try heredoc syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers. I didn't even need to use any of them though. `echo include("MyFileName.html");` worked just fine without using `addslashes()`.