# echo HTML in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Before I asked this question I went through [How to echo in PHP, html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931351/how-to-echo-in-php-html-tags) but I couldn't come up with a solution. I'm trying to echo some HTML in PHP. I am using the Codeigniter framework. When I select a category I want to load the view using an Ajax request.
I am using jQuery to send the request and load the page inside the div. Everything works well but when I use PHP it doesn't give me proper output.
I wrote the following code:

```
echo '<a href="google.com"><img src="newone.jpg" /></a>';
```

It produces the output as "</a>" with double quotation.

This is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#category").change(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "post",
            url :  "controller_list/get_images",
            data : "categoryid="+jQuery("#category").val(),
            dataType: "html",
            success : function(msg) 
            {
                jQuery("div").find("#img_list").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: code is perfect, give full url for google.com like `echo '<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="newone.jpg" /></a>';`

Comment: not working. bad luck :( thanks for the reply

Comment: @SandeepNayak `img` tags are self closing, that is legal syntax.

Comment: @RUJordan: Sorry. You are right. Overlooked that `img` tag.

Comment: change single quotes to double and double quotes to single: echo "<a href='www.google.com'><img src='newone.jpg' ></a>"

Comment: it may be codeigniter issue.when I click on the produced output it is redirected to localhost/test/\"http:\/\/google.com\"
my base url is localhost/test.

Comment: @IshaS: Write you `href` as suggested by @Dev.

Comment: @Sandeep Nayak: I wrote as he suggested.but it is not working.

Comment: @IshaS u r using codeigniter ok?? then where you putting this code? may be image url not found.

Comment: `<?php echo '<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/earth1.jpg"/></a>';  ?>` for me this is working perfect, check your url and image path properly. Hope you figure it out

Comment: If you are using **`$.ajax`**, check for **`dataType : 'html'`** that is set in the params.

Comment: @IJas set data type as html.no changes

Comment: Can you provide the codes ? JS codes for the ajax request and the Codeigniter Method codes.

Comment: ok.. I put JS code to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was fixed after changing dataType: "html" to dataType: "json"