# Enclose echo with html

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this code of php that I want to add an `<h3>` html. tried to add an `<h3>` html in between the content but it got me an error.

```
echo __('Din indkøbskurv er tom. ', 'wpsc') . '<a href=' . esc_url( get_option( 'product_list_url', '' ) ) . ">" . __('Besøg venligst vores butik', 'wpsc') . '</a>';
```

I think this is the whole code.

```
<?php
global $wpsc_cart, $wpdb, $wpsc_checkout, $wpsc_gateway, $wpsc_coupons, $wpsc_registration_error_messages;
$wpsc_checkout = new wpsc_checkout();
$alt = 0;
$coupon_num = wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'coupon' );
if( $coupon_num )
   $wpsc_coupons = new wpsc_coupons( $coupon_num );

if(wpsc_cart_item_count() < 1) :
    echo __('Din indkøbskurv er tom. ', 'wpsc') . '<a href=' . esc_url( get_option( 'product_list_url', '' ) ) . ">" . __('Besøg venligst vores butik', 'wpsc') . '</a>';
    return;
endif;
?>
```

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931351/how-to-echo-in-php-html-tags) but it doesn't work.

Comment: *"it got me an error"* - being? *"i think this is the whole code"* - Oh?

Comment: what part of the code do you want to make a header?

Comment: this is what i added. <h3> . ('Din indkøbskurv er tom. ', 'wpsc') . '<a href=' . esc_url( get_option( 'product_list_url', '' ) ) . ">" . __('Besøg venligst vores butik', 'wpsc') . '</a>' . </h3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay try this (not any HTML tags are read as text, so they need to exist within quotes)

```
('<h3> Din indkøbskurv er tom. ', 'wpsc') . '<a href=' . esc_url( get_option( 'product_list_url', '' ) ) . ">" . __('Besøg venligst vores butik', 'wpsc') . '</a></h3>';
```

Comment: I'd recommend pulling the `<h3>` out of the first translation string since it's code and not text

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using `sprintf()` to make your code more readable and localization easier:

```
$product_list_url = esc_url( get_option( 'product_list_url', '' ) );
echo sprintf( __('Din indkøbskurv er tom. <a href="%s">Besøg venligst vores</a>', 'wpsc' ), $product_list_url );
```