# How can I echo the actual HTML tags with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I was thinking of maybe using PHP to automate some of the more tedious tasks of HTML while still generating a totally static page that doesn't require a back end.  What I'm trying to do is simply print a large amount of `<p></p>` tags separated by line breaks

I've glanced at this page [How to echo in PHP, html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931351/how-to-echo-in-php-html-tags)

Here is my code

```
<?php

    $t= "this is the text";

    foreach(range(1,25) as $number) {
            echo '<p>' . $t . '</p>';
            echo "</br>";

    }

?>
```

What it does prints two line breaks, one for the `<p>` tags and one for the `</br>` but does not actually print the `<p>` tags themselves, how can I get it to print the `<p>` and `</p>` tags as text and then echo a line break.

Comment: you want to print the literal `<`, `p`, and `>` characters? Then `echo '&lt;p&gt;`

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `htmlentities` to render the `p` tags as text.

```
echo htmlentities('<p>' . $t . '</p>');
echo '<br>';
```

Use the `PHP_EOL` constant to add a new line character the html ouput.

```
echo '<p>' . $t . '</p>';
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

USe it ,this could be work

```
echo "&lt;p&gt; helo &lt;/p&gt; <br>";
```