# escape html tags in a php echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an AJAX contact form and within the success message i would like to add html tags however when i do, it prints the tags so it shows as...

```
  <p>Thank You! You are unsubscribed.</p>
```

how can i amend the following?

```
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo '<p>Thank You! You are unsubscribed.</p>';
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }
```

it doesnt seem as easy as this [How to echo in PHP, html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931351/how-to-echo-in-php-html-tags)

and i can't integrate document.write

Comment: SO what is your problem ??

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI - It's a straight forward question.. He doesn't want the html tags to show..

Comment: the message shows the html tags <p> and </p> whereas i want it to recognise the html tags

Comment: This is what you're looking for: http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php
@MASIDDIQUI The question is completly clear...

Comment: Where are you running the code .. in browser or cli .. in browser it won't show.. in cli it will

Comment: This question lacks basic info. I suspect you call this code from AJAX using JavaScript and such JavaScript handles response data as plain text.