# How to put php table into html sidebar?

Tags: php, html, css

Hi im a begginer in php and html i would like to ask how do i put this table into my html sidelist. when i put my table inside that space this always appear ( "; foreach($testaroni as $x=>$y) { echo ""; echo "" . $y . ""; } echo ""; echo ""; ?>)
This is my table. [This is the problem (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLnis.png)

```
<?php
session_start();
$testaroni = explode("', '" , $_SESSION["data"]);
?>

<?php
echo "<table border = '1'>";
foreach($testaroni as $x=>$y) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $y . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

And i would like to put it inside here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
stroke: #999;
stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
}


</style>



<?php
session_start();
$testaroni = explode("', '" , $_SESSION["data"]);
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-blue-grey w3-bar-block " style="width:15%">
<h4 class="w3-bar-item">Sidelist</h4> 


<table border = "1">
<?php
foreach($testaroni as $x=>$y) {
echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>' . $y . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

?>   
</table>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit your code and paste what is in your local copy atm?

Comment: the rest of the code is a d3,js graph that i put beside this sidebar

Comment: I mean just replace `***[I WOULD LIKE TO PUT THAT TABLE HERE]***` with your table code

Comment: Your code should work that's why I wanna see what you're doing with it now in that spot

Comment: i have edited the code and added a image link of the problem ontop

Comment: You can move `<table border = '1'>` and `</table>` outside the php tags.

Comment: Sorry man still no luck i have updated the image ontop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify your explode function and your code will work as you want

```
session_start();
//lets say your $_SESSION["data"] contains
$_SESSION["data"] = 'Value1,Value2,Value3';
//$testaroni = explode("', '" , $_SESSION["data"]);// just use single or double quotes without space
$testaroni = explode("," , $_SESSION["data"]);
```

Comment: Could you please print your $_SESSION["data"] variable using print_r($_SESSION["data"]) ? so that i will be cleared what its cotains

Comment: java', 'c++', 'sybase', 'marketing', 'chemistry', 'sql', 'unix shell', 'general programming', 'javascript', 'xml', 'j2ee

Comment: I have checked it and create a test file which is working fine.

Comment: Is your server running?

Comment: Yeah using wamp server its running i tried to create the table on a test file is works but only when i put it in my sidebar it doesnt show

Answer (score 0):

You try var_dump( $_SESSION["data"]) and you should check empty  $_SESSION["data"].I try put

> $testaroni = array("1","2","3");//it work fine

Comment: testarr.php:3:string 'firewall', 'java', 'c++', 'sybase', 'marketing', 'chemistry', 'sql', 'unix shell', 'general programming', 'javascript', 'xml', 'j2ee' (length=132) this is what it showed

Comment: sorry, i can't help you . But i see you write residual </form> tag and I think you should set Sesson is JSON type, it will be better

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about my this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931351/how-to-echo-in-php-html-tags)

Seems like my eyes are failing me took me a while to see it.

You shouldn't use `"` when trying to use HTML tags in PHP

What you need to use is `'`.

```
<table border = "1">
<tr>
<?php
foreach($testaroni as $x=>$y) {
     echo '<td>'.$y.'</td>';
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

The reason for this is that `"` will treat anything inside it as string while `'` will treat it as is.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) for a better explanation.

Also, follow the answer above for your session since it's also wrong.

Comment: so i only have to change this part echo '<td>'.$y.'</td>';? and the rest is ok?

Comment: FWIW - simply a matter of style, but the quotes issue can be avoided by using this format when outputting html - `<?php foreach($testaroni as $y): ?> <td><?= $y ?></td><?php endforeach; ?>` (This trivial example doesn't do it justice, but with more html it starts to look much clearer than echoes and quotes all over the place)

Comment: Yes, or you can stick with your template and just change `"` to `'`. Tim comment is worth noting as well it's cleaner and avoid a lot of echoes :)

Comment: i have changed it but it still doesnt work i have edited the code ^

Comment: just above the `foreach` add this `echo "hello"; die;` and tell me the result

Answer (score 0):

Your session variable is a CSV string.  simply exploding on the comma isn't going to get what you're looking for.  You can verify this with `var_dump($testaroni);`.

Use `str_getcsv`.

```
<?php
// always start with php logic; 
// it makes the script much easier to follow and 
// if you need to redirect, you haven't put out any output yet.

session_start();

// check the docs for info on this function
$testaroni = str_getcsv($_SESSION['data']);

// then, when everything is calculated, print out your output
?>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Search</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
      <style>

      .links line {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: 0.6;
      }

      .nodes circle {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

      text {
      font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
      }


      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="w3-sidebar w3-blue-grey w3-bar-block " style="width:15%">
        <h4 class="w3-bar-item">Sidelist</h4> 
        <table border = "1">
        <?php foreach($testaroni as $y): ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?= $y ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't pay any attention to the css styling and inline styling.  I don't know what the w3schools stylesheet does.  Do you at least get the list of items in your session variable?  Can't help any more tonight, but you can debug by simply using `var_dump` to see if a variable is what you expect.

Comment: yeah i created a test table on another page it works the problem is just getting the table inside that sidebar