# echoing HTML with echo <<< HTML

Tags: php, html, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a reason to use Heredoc in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673269/is-there-a-reason-to-use-heredoc-in-php)

I'm new to PHP.

Is it good practice to use something like that?

```
echo <<< HTML
        <a href="$link" title="$title">$item</a>
HTML;
```

It does work, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Thanks very much...

Comment: Refer to this:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use single-quotes, double-quotes, heredoc and nowdoc, depending on what you need (formatting, variables inside, etc.). See more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Mixing HTML and PHP in the same file is **never** a good practice. Separate code and templates by putting them in different files and possibly using a template engine.

However, if you **need** to put blocks of HTML in a PHP file the *heredoc* syntax you used in your example is perfectly fine as it avoids the escaping hell you'd have when using regular quotes.

For the various ways of quoting strings have a look at the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). It also explains how the various strings behave (e.g. regarding variable interpolation and escape sequences).