# Run PHP code while echoing PHP

Tags: php

I'm using the echo command in PHP, but I want to enter PHP code like `<?php echo $variable [id_login]?>`, while echoing something else out, but this does not work.

Is this possible to do, and if so, how would I do it?

```
echo "<script>location='member.php?&id=<?php echo $taruh[id_login] ?></script>";
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't include images for code, just update your question with the relevant code (as text).

Comment: `echo '<script>location="member.php?id=' . $taruh['id_login'] . '";</script>';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you put PHP inside PHP with echo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228026/can-you-put-php-inside-php-with-echo)

Comment: What is your output, and why do you think it does not work?

Comment: i want include id_login from database and redirect this in url like http://localhost/folder/member.php?id=1

Comment: this code echo '<script>location="member.php?id=' . $taruh['id_login'] . '";</script>'; not work!! output in url like this member.php?id= *blank

Comment: @KicauManiaKudus Are you sure that `$taruh['id_login']` isn't blank?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use echo or open/cloce `php` twice like you did, you might want to try something like the line below,

```
echo '<script>location=member.php?id=' . $taruh[id_login] . '</script>';
```

after `echo` you can write enything you'd like, even if it's a php variable, just use single quote and dot where you need it (like I do here), as you can see, echo is only used once..

For example:

```
<?php
$your_variable = 'some text';
$other_variable = 'some PHP code';
echo 'I wrote: ' . $your_variable . ' and ' . $other_variable . '&#33;';
?>
```

Output will be:

I wrote: some text and some PHP code!

I hope this will bring you into the right direction..

### EDIT

Also important: if you use  query string in URLs, the first 1 can be a `?` every other part after should be a `&` for example see the url below

`http://www.example.com/index.php?id=12345&coder=yes&country=usa`

before `id` I used a quest sign, for all others I didn't use the quest sign...