# Set dropdown list value inside PHP Echo

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, echo

I'm having problem on select value on the `dropdown list`.

**What I have tried:**

As currently I have no problem set value inside pure `html` and some `php` for logic
in order to set the value. As show in this example:

```
<?php $temp_val = 3; ?>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1" <?php if($temp_val == "1") echo("selected='selected'")?>>1</option>
            <option value="2" <?php if($temp_val == "2") echo("selected='selected'")?>>2</option>
            <option value="3" <?php if($temp_val == "3") echo("selected='selected'")?>>3</option>
            <option value="4" <?php if($temp_val == "4") echo("selected='selected'")?>>4</option>
            <option value="5" <?php if($temp_val == "5") echo("selected='selected'")?>>5</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

In this case, it should select number 3, and the result does works like this:

[image]

As seen here, everything works as expected with pure `html` and some `php`.

**The Problem**

Currently I would like use the same logic inside `php echo()`, which means I need to put php code inside a php code with `echo`. As I have researched it is not possible as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228026/can-you-put-php-inside-php-with-echo).

As I have tried to implement inside `php echo code` and this is the result:

```
<?php
$temp_val = 3;
    echo "<td>
       <select>
           <option value='1' <?php if($temp_val == '1') echo('selected='selected'')?>1</option>
           <option value='2' <?php if($temp_val == '2') echo('selected='selected'')?>2</option>
           <option value='3' <?php if($temp_val == '3') echo('selected='selected'')?>3</option>
           <option value='4' <?php if($temp_val == '4') echo('selected='selected'')?>4</option>
           <option value='5' <?php if($temp_val == '5') echo('selected='selected'')?>5</option>
       </select>
    </td>";
?>
```

When combining I made some subtle changes from `"` to `'` as it might interfere with echo. At this point, there must be something wrong. and this is the result:

[image]

As of why it shows 3 of them, because I need looped with echo and php, that's the reason I'm unable to use pure html to accomplish the task. Does anyone have the similar problem?

Thanks for the time, and have a nice day.

Comment: Should use double quotes? `echo('selected="selected"')`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond. if I try use double quotes, it interfere with echo, is there a escape keyword for it?. EDIT: I have tried escape with \" but still same result. Maybe I should not put php inside php as linked question provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this

```
<?php $temp_val = 3; ?> 
<td> 
    <select>
        <?php
            For($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
        ?>
            <option value="<?= $i; ?>" <?php if($temp_val == $i) echo("selected")?>>
                <?= $i ?>
            </option> 
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: what will happen if i use <?= instead of <?php all around

Comment: This will help you to directly print variable. Instead of using echo you can use <?= ?>

Answer (score 1):

For understanding, I have to tell you about 2 things:

**First,** You don't need use echo inside echo, just use it once.

**Second,** You can't use single quote inside single quote or double quote inside double quote. But, If you want do that, you must add backslash. Like this `echo "<option value=\"$value\">$text</option>";`

And for your problem above, I recommending to use function. You can create a function to make selected at option value.

```
function set_selected($val1, $val2) {
    if ($val1 == $val2) {
       echo 'selected="selected"';
    }
}
```

And then, in your code:

```
<?php
$temp_val = 3;
    echo "<td>
       <select>
           <option value='1' set_selected($temp_val, '1') >1</option>
           ...
       </select>
    </td>";
?>
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not echoing out the second selected due to the single quotes, just do:

```
 <?php if($temp_val == '1') echo('selected')?>
```

All the option needs is 'selected'. 
I really like taking the logic out of the HTML, however in this case it would result in several variables being defined. I guess it's up to your person preference.

I hope this helps!