# displaying php variable on browser is OK but does not work when inserted into html page

Tags: php, html

I've-yet-to-meet
About 30 years ago, I wrote, in Commodore basic, a small arithmetic program for my children and have been trying to "replicate" it using html & php. Using this code it does what I want, when the file(test.php) is run in IE8, i.e. it displays the value of the variables (except the \r\n do not give a line break), Like so: What is 4 + 15? 4 + 15 = 19
    
However, this is not the case when the same code, including tags is inserted into an html page; below
    
    
    A web page

```
<body bgcolor="#fefee8">
<p><H1 align="center"> <font color="#00c630">Page header</font></H1> </p>       
<HR> <!HR provides horizontal line below the TOPH>
</body>

<BR><!line break tag
</font> </br> 
<body>  
<P align="center"> <font color="#707070">
<div>
<?php
$a=rand (2, 20);
$b=rand (2, 20);
$c=$a+$b;
print "What is $a + $b? \r\n";
print " $a + $b = $c";
?>
</div>
</Body> 
</html>
```

I am teaching myself the html and PHP as I go along, and have scoured the search engines for guidance but I cannot find much succour there, so appeal to you.
My resources are Notepad++ as my editor, Apache as my localhost web server, and my guidebooks are SAMS Teach yourself PHP and IDG's Teach yourself HTML 4 (yes I know they are old). My hardware is Lenovo Thinkpad, Win XP (SP3) with IE8. 
It never was this difficult with Basic, (but the graphics sucked) :-), Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `<br/>` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is caused because you are using your code in a .html document. If you save the document as a PHP file (.php) with your notepad++ then your code will work :)

Comment: @patricksweeney Yes, look at the title.. displaying php variable on browser is OK but does not work when inserted into html page.. PHP variable, in a HTML page.. His code is fine, if used in a PHP file..

Comment: @user3356094. Spot on, my friend. Simply saving it as .php and it works a treat. Now to find out what's next; as I said much easier with BASIC :D, Thank you.

Comment: Well hopefully the original poster noted that they specifically stated they saved it as .php originally - gotta love when OP says when thing when they mean another :)

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotation marks (") (the real name escapes me), PHP does not take it liturally. Try using:

```
print 'What is ' . $a . ' + ' . $b . '?<br>';
print $a . ' +  ' . $b . ' = ' . $c;
```

< br > is a break in the display.

Comment: Using single quotes and variables directly will not work - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/1603275

Comment: @Kami my mistake, it was a long day. Edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Kami and James. Thank you both. FYI, it works OK with double quotes and thanks for the <br> update, but the "fixer" was saving it as .php not as .html. Doesn't matter how old one gets, one lives and learns so thanks again. I guess this Q can be  closed now??

Comment: @user3379909 Ah, did not see that one coming. I assumed you had saved it as php, lol.  To mark the question as closed, click the accept answer link next to the response that answered your question.