# Writing welcome message with username PHP

Tags: php

Hi really quick question, i was wandering how i can output a string alongside a username which is generated using sessions

i want the code to say something like : "Welcome, (username)"

**This is my code so far which outputs the username of the person logged in, but i want to add "welcome" in front of the username.**

```
<?php
   if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   echo '<div id="welcome_msg">'  .$_SESSION['username']. '</div>';
                                }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add non-PHP content within quotes in echo statement like:

```
   echo '<div id="welcome_msg">Welcome '  .$_SESSION['username']. '</div>';
```

Comment: ahh okay thank you for the reply, you can tell im very new to this stuff aha :) when 12 mins is up i can put this as the correct answer

Comment: You're welcome. You can refer to following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php for more information

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
  {
      echo "<div id='welcome_msg'>Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']."</div>";
  }
```

If you may want, you can even style the username with bold, or italic or underline with , and  respectively. e.g. to bolden the username;

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
  {
      echo "<div id='welcome_msg'><b>Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']."</b></div>";
  }
```