# How do you use echo inside html table row?

Tags: php, html, echo

I am using `echo` inside the HTML `tr` tag where I am getting an error.

Here is my code

**index.php**

```
<?php
$i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))
    {
    if($i%2==0)
$classname="evenRow";
else
$classname="oddRow";
echo '<tr class="id" >';
echo '<tr class="'echo $classname'">';
?>
```

I am getting following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\pagination\index.php on line 64

Where am I going wrong and how can I achieve my desired output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Echo inside echo?!!!

Comment: i tried with one echo no working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php?rq=1

Comment: See my answer. Hope it'll give you light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you are inside a table row, but that you are inside a PHP string, and the answer is: You don't.

You either:

- Interpolate your variable
- Concatenate your variable
- Don't use echo and a string for the outside output

Such:

```
<?php
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros)) {
    if($i%2==0) {
        $classname="evenRow";
    } else {
        $classname="oddRow";
?>
<tr class="id">
    <tr class="<?php echo $classname; ?>">
<?php
    }
# ...
```

NB: You appear to be trying to nest table rows, which isn't allowed.

You can probably dispense with the odd/even class names and just [use `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this. Don't echo twice!

```
echo '<tr class=" '. $classname .' ">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
<?php
$i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))
    {
    if($i%2==0)
$classname="evenRow";
else
$classname="oddRow";
echo '<tr class="id" >';
echo '<tr class="'.$classname.'">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))
{
    if($i%2==0)
        $classname="evenRow";
    else
        $classname="oddRow";

    echo "<tr class='id'>";
    echo "<tr class=".$classname.">";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not use `echo` inside an `echo`

```
echo '<tr class="'echo $classname'">';
```

Use it like this

```
echo '<tr class="'.$classname.'">';
```