# PHP - include large sections of html in PHP

Tags: php, html

i want to include many lines of HTML code, only if a certain condition in PHP is true.

## Example:

```
<?
    if ($var == 1){
       WriteTheHTML:
    }
?>

    ... <b> This is only displayed if condition is fulfilled </b> ...

<?  StopWritingTheHTML; ?>
```

I just don't want to have multiple files. Also, i want to avoid writing the HTML code in PHP echo.

Is there a (similar) solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I echo HTML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It seems that i didn't search deep enough, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
<?php   if ($var == 1){  ?>
   ... <b> This is only displayed if condition is fulfilled </b> ...
<?php  }else{  ?>
   ... <b> This is only displayed if condition is fulfilled </b> ...
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend you use the [alternative syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1100373/300836) that's meant for just this situation if you're going to do that...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna keep it clean you should use a "template engine". There are really small ones - see mine:

Template engine:

```
    class TemplateEngine {
        /**
         * Contains the Templatecontent
         *
         * @access    private
         * @var       array
         */
        private $TEMPLATE_VARS = array();

       /**
         * Contains the Blockdiretory
         *
         * @access    private
         * @var       string
         */
        private $BLOCK_DIR='';

        /**
         * @param string $pos Set the position in the Template
         * @param string $cont Set the content at this position
         */
        public function assign($pos, $cont = null) {
            $this->TEMPLATE_VARS[$pos] = $cont;
        }
        /**
         * @param string $tpl_file Set the Maintemplate 
         */
        public function display($tpl_file) {
            if (!empty($tpl_file)) {
                if (file_exists($tpl_file)) {                
                    $TPL = $this->TEMPLATE_VARS;                
                    include($tpl_file);               
                } else {
                    echo "File doesnt exist";
                    echo $tpl_file;
                }
            } else {
                echo "File is empty";
            }
        }

        /**
         * @param string $pos Set the position in the Template
         * @param array $cont Set the content at this position (mostly used with arrays to fill the blocks)
         */
        public function content($pos, $cont = null) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($cont); $i++) {
                $this->TEMPLATE_VARS[$pos][$i] = $cont[$i];
            }
        }

    }
    ?>
```

The template (template.tpl.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 
<html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="<?php echo $_SESSION["language"] ?>" lang="<?php echo $_SESSION["language"] ?>"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>           
        <meta charset="utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title><?php echo $TPL['title'] ?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php
        if (isset($TPL['description'])) {
            echo $TPL['description'];
        }
        ?>"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?php
        if (isset($TPL['keywords'])) {
            echo $TPL['keywords'];
        }
        ?>"/>        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <!-- Mobile viewport optimisation -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
        <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public"/>      
        <!--Load Scripts-->
        <?php
        foreach ($TPL['headElements'] as $element)
            echo $element . PHP_EOL
            ?>         
    </head>        
    <body>  
        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--include blocks-->
        <?php
        foreach ($TPL['blocks'] as $element)
            include $element;
        ?>

        <!-- Load footersection-->
        <?php
        foreach ($TPL['footElements'] as $element)
            echo $element . PHP_EOL
            ?>                 
    </body> 
</html>
```

And now you can include blocks into that template by doing following:

```
 $tpl = new TemplateEngine;
    $tpl->assign("title", "Your title");   
    //Blocks
    $tpl->assign("blocks", array(PATH . "/web/blocks/content/registerPage.php", PATH . "/web/blocks/footerWrap.php"));
    $tpl->assign("register", PATH . "/web/blocks/register.php");


    $tpl->assign("footElements", returnFooter());

    $tpl->display(PATH . "/web/template.tpl.php");
```