# How can i echo a variable from my database inside my echo?

Tags: php

Okay so i was wondering how i echo a variable from a database that i already have connected to a php script so basicly it would be like

```
echo '<img src="blablabla.com/VARIABLENAMEHERE" />'
```

Comment: Concatenate or use double quotes. If you use double quotes use single quotes to encapsulate your attributes. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/The-Basics.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I echo HTML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes, and then variables will be expanded inside the string:

```
echo "<img src='blablabla.com/$variable' />";
```

Or user string concatenation:

```
echo '<img src="blablabla.com/' . $variable . '" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use double quotes as the double quotes evaluates the variable inside.

```
echo "<img src='blablabla.com/$variablename' />";
```

but if you insist using single quote you can use concatenation.

```
echo '<img src="blablabla.com/' . $variablename . '" />';
```

Comment: How exactly does this differ from the already posted answer which was posted an hour ago.