# Put a php function inside an echo html

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to include a function inside an HTML that is showed as an echo in a php file, how can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

**Function:** `self::showMap($item);`

**The echo:**

```
<?php
    echo "<html lang='en'>
    <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8' />
      <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' />
      <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
      <script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'></script>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href=''/resources/demos/style.css' />
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( '#tabs' ).tabs();
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='tabs'>
      <ul>
      <li><a href='#tabs-1'>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tabs-2'>Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tabs-3'>Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id='tabs-1'>
        <p>FUNCTION GOES HERE</p>
      </div>
      <div id='tabs-2'>
        <p>tab two content.</p>
      </div>
      <div id='tabs-3'>
        <p>tab three content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>";

?>
```

Comment: what is issue ?

Comment: `"html" . some_function() . "rest of html"`    ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I echo HTML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$function  = self::showMap($item);

"Html $function Html......";
if you are using double codes in HTML, no need to concatenate, it'll appear as value.

Comment: I redefined the function, this solved the issue, thanks!