# Clickable echo $query['name'];

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code.
I want it to be clickable leading to another site in a new tab.
Also when hover change color.

```html
echo $query['name'];
```

Comment: so what's issue?

Comment: [How can I echo HTML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php)

Comment: You want to learn the basics of html and how the web works. This is nothing we should answer, you should simply read and work through a basic tutorial. There are hundreds only a short google search away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
echo "<a href='url' id='myLink' target='_blank'>".$query['name']."</a>";
```

This will open your url in a new tab.

And you can have the following styles to make it behave as a clickable text which changes its color to red on hover

```
#myLink {
    text-decoration: none; //remove this if you want a link
    color: black;  //remove this line if you want a blue link
    cursor: pointer;
}
 #myLink:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

Let me know if you require any further help

Answer (score 1):

You can make it as a link give it id and change css

```
echo "<a href='another_page_url' id='checking'>".$query['name']."</a>";
```

On style sheet

```
 #checking:hover{
    color:yellow;
}
```