# Append Json questions to html

Tags: php, html, json

I'm currently trying to append **all** the questions from `questions.json` to my main `PHP` page and I would like to do it dynamically.

I've searched for tutorials and when I copy-paste the code it works, but when I change it with mine, it doesn't. I'm still a newbie who is learning, so please don't throw at me bunch of complex code. Much appreciated !

**questions.json:**

```
{"Theme": "Montpellier",
    "url" : "correction.php",
    "questions": [ 
        {"question": " Combien sommes-nous?", "reponses": [{"choix": "3"},{"choix": "43"},{"choix": "5"}]},
        {"question": "Selon sa demographie quelle est le classement de Montpellier?","reponses": [{"choix": "8eme"},{"choix": "5eme"},{"choix": "2eme"}]},
        {"question": "Autour de quelle date la fête des lumières ce deroulle-t-elle? ","reponses": [{"choix": "31 Novembre"},{"choix": "6 Septembre"},{"choix": "18 Juillet"}]},
        {"question": " Combien de lignes de trameway y'a t-il à Montpellier?","reponses": [{"choix": "4"},{"choix": "5"},{"choix": "2"}]},
        {"question": "Quelle est le plus grand Campus de Montpellier? ","reponses": [{"choix": "fac des sciences"},{"choix": "fac d'economie"},{"choix": "fac de droit"}]},
        {"question": "Quelle est la place la plus vivante à Montpellier?","reponses": [{"choix": "Comedie"},{"choix": "Gare Saint-Roch"},{"choix": "Peyrou"}]}
    ]
}
```

Edit: I tried using this code and currently it isn't echoing anything.

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("questionnaire.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($json_a as $question => $reponses) {
    echo $reponses['choix'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Start by parsing the JSON... `json_decode()`.

Comment: I've tried this above, currently not being able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

*reponses* is an array, so you'll have to iterate it to echo the choices:

```
<?php
foreach($json_a['questions'] as $q) {
    echo "\n\n" . $q['question'] . "\n";
    foreach ($q['reponses'] as $r) {
        echo "\t" . $r['choix'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what are you doing, but may I ask how can I include the json into the .php file, so the iteration could actually know where to search for the array questions ?

I mean for JS is `<script type="text/javascript href="..."></script>`

How does that work for json ?

Comment: You can't do that in PHP. What you're doing with `file_get_contents` is fine.

Comment: Alright, I managed to echo all the questions and answers one, but it seems that "\n" isn't being registered at all. Do you know how can I make it to echo all the questions and answers but put before that an <input type="radio"> and to wrap it up in a <form>, so it actually has questions with clickable answers ?

Comment: Sure, @NikolaStoilov :) What you want is to output HTML with PHP. It's one of the most common uses of PHP, so I'd suggest you to read this question and answer. It'll definitely help you achieve what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1100354/1534704