# Unable to beautify php echo statements

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have developed one webpage using php .
I am executing some shell scripts through it and the shell scripts return some outputs (echo statements) . Those echo statements  are saved in output1 , output2 etc ..
This is the piece of code where I am redirecting those outputs to  a text area.

```
<textarea>
 <?php
 echo $output1 ;
 echo $output1 ;
 ?>
</textarea>
```

The output is getting correctly printed in text area. I need to make those statements bold , colourful . But I cant do the same.  If I add span style colour and all inside the echo , the whole thing is getting printed in text area. Please help .

Thanks

Comment: try this : `echo '<b>'.$output1.'</b>';`

Comment: Have you ever seen a plain textarea with anything but plain text?

Comment: Could use something like TinyMCE or CKEdit I guess; they're WYSIWYG editors that "hijack" a given text area allowing you to format the text in-situ ... but if this isn't supposed to be editable (as it's just responses from shell) why put it into a `<textarea>` at all?

Comment: @prakashtank Its not working . <b> coming in text area.

Answer (score 2):

`textarea`s cannot be formatted; use some other element that *can* be formatted, such as a div.

```css
.output {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>normal</div>
<div class="output">output1 code</div>
<div class="output">output2 code</div>
```

like

```
<div class="output><?= $output1 ?></div>
<div class="output><?= $output2 ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Early Night by Rafal Tomal**

```
h1 { color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 54px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 58px; margin: 0 0 58px; }
```

## The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog!

Edit::
You can use the contenteditable attribute. It is as follows:

```
<?php echo"
    <div id='mytxt' contenteditable='true'>
       Hello, my name is <span style='color: blue;'>Bob</span>
       and I have a friend name <span style='color: green;'>Joe</span>.
    </div>";
```

You can add the html in php for more information go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100424/9025311)

Comment: I'm really struggling to work out the relevance of this to the original question tbh...

Comment: @CD001 he asks about beautiful text,there you go,it's a css question not a php

Comment: It's about formatting text in a `<textarea>` block; presumably with inline formatting so there might be some pink bold text and some that's green italic... which we both know can't be done (without a load of JS).

Comment: @CD001 I see but I found smth

Comment: @D.'s Its not a CSS question. I am priting echo in php . I need php itself. So my question is how to add beautification to the echo statements getting printed by php code

Comment: @NagarajKulkarni you mean this `echo '<input type="text" style...>';`

Comment: @D.'s Yes . I need code like this . integrated inside echo statement. Could you please post the whole command

Comment: @NagarajKulkarni did it work?dont forget to mark it as an answer

Comment: No . It didnt help. It is printing the whole thing as text. Need some alternatives. Am working on the same.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more of a css question. You can add this css style for your text area:

```css
textarea {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
```