# How to output this string?

Tags: php, string, escaping

I'm new to php and I need to assign these two strings to variables and echo them exactly as seen below:

String 1:

```
<div class='annoying_string' id="garbage">Programming & PHP rules \\ must try</div>
```

String 2:

```
(?:(?:\r\n)?"[ \t]")*(?:(?:(?:'[^()<>@,;:\\".\'[\]' \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
```

I apologize in advance as I'm sure this question's aspects have all been answered multiple times - I did see quite a number of related articles, and I read about escaping with backslashes and stuff but in this string there are "s, 's, \s, practically everything and I fail to see how I can 'escape' all of them...

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has worked? What hasn’t? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You might look into [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I echo HTML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing around with escaping, it may be much simpler to use a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
$string1 = <<<'EOD'
<div class='annoying_string' id="garbage">Programming & PHP rules \\ must try</div>
EOD;

$string2 = <<<'EOD'
(?:(?:\r\n)?"[ \t]")*(?:(?:(?:'[^()<>@,;:\\".\'[\]' \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
EOD;
```