# How to show a form after a conditional

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm starting at php and I want to put a form after a conditional.

```
if ($_POST) {
$busqueda = trim($_POST['buscar']);
$entero = 0;
if (empty($busqueda)) {
    $texto = 'Búsqueda sin resultados';
} else {
    conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE cups LIKE '%" . $busqueda . "%' ORDER BY cups";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
        $registros = '<p>Hemos encontrado ' . mysqli_num_rows($resultado) . ' registros </p>'
        ;
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $texto.= $fila['cups'] . '<br />';
        }
    } else {
        $texto = "No hay resultados en la BBDD";
    }
} else (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
    echo 
         ;
}
```

When it shows "Hemos encontrado X registros" I want to put a form to fill more entries to the table, but I can't find the way to do that.
Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm really noob at this!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those two consecutive `else`s... Anyway, just do `?> <form> ... </form> <?php` where you want the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I echo HTML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100354/how-can-i-echo-html-in-php)

Comment: @FedericoKlezCulloca thanks for your answer. I edited the code because I copied the wrong one.

Comment: Just FYI, changing the indentation doesn't change the fact that that second `else` is misplaced.